# org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: of content type: application/json

Tags: java, rest, api

Here is my model:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dwidasa.kse.ksei.model;

/**
 *
 * @author asus
 */
public class ParticipantMsg {


    private String participantCode;
    private String ktpNumber;
    private String namaLengkap;
    private String tanggalLahir;
    private String jenisKelamin;
    private String noRekeningInvestor;
    private String nationality;
    private String tipeInvestor;
    private String reason;

    public String getParticipantCode() {
        return participantCode;
    }

    public void setParticipantCode(String participantCode) {
        this.participantCode = participantCode;
    }

    public String getKtpNumber() {
        return ktpNumber;
    }

    public void setKtpNumber(String ktpNumber) {
        this.ktpNumber = ktpNumber;
    }

    public String getNamaLengkap() {
        return namaLengkap;
    }

    public void setNamaLengkap(String namaLengkap) {
        this.namaLengkap = namaLengkap;
    }

    public String getTanggalLahir() {
        return tanggalLahir;
    }

    public void setTanggalLahir(String tanggalLahir) {
        this.tanggalLahir = tanggalLahir;
    }

    public String getJenisKelamin() {
        return jenisKelamin;
    }

    public void setJenisKelamin(String jenisKelamin) {
        this.jenisKelamin = jenisKelamin;
    }

    public String getNoRekeningInvestor() {
        return noRekeningInvestor;
    }

    public void setNoRekeningInvestor(String noRekeningInvestor) {
        this.noRekeningInvestor = noRekeningInvestor;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public String getTipeInvestor() {
        return tipeInvestor;
    }

    public void setTipeInvestor(String tipeInvestor) {
        this.tipeInvestor = tipeInvestor;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

}
```

Here is my server code:

```
package com.dwidasa.ib.services;

import com.dwidasa.engine.json.PojoJsonMapper;
import com.dwidasa.ib.annotations.NoValidate;
import com.dwidasa.kse.ksei.model.ParticipantMsg;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.cache.NoCache;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

@Path("/dukcapil")
@NoCache
public abstract interface KSEIDukcapilResource
{
    @NoValidate
    @POST
    @Produces({"application/json;charset=utf-8"})
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("inquiryKSEI")
    public abstract String inquiryNIK(@Context HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, 
                @RequestBody ParticipantMsg msg);
  }
```

Here is my messagebodyreader code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dwidasa.kse.ksei.service;

import com.dwidasa.kse.ksei.model.ParticipantMsg;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;


/**
 *
 * @author asus
 */
@Provider
@Consumes("application/json")
public class ParticipantBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<ParticipantMsg> {
    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                              Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == ParticipantMsg.class;
    }

    @Override
    public ParticipantMsg readFrom(Class<ParticipantMsg> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                         MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
                         InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ParticipantMsg.class);
            return (ParticipantMsg) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(entityStream);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
//            throw new ProcessingException("Error deserializing user.", e);
            throw new WebApplicationException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

I make REST API as server, but when I hit from postman, it was always get error.
"org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.dwidasa.kse.ksei.model.ParticipantMsg of content type: application/json" ?